# How to extract a node attribute from XML using PHP's DOM Parser

Tags: php, xml, dom

I've never really used the DOM parser before and now I have a question.

How would I go about extracting the URL from this markup:

```
<files>
    <file path="http://www.thesite.com/download/eysjkss.zip" title="File Name" />
</files>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using simpleXML:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
echo $xml->file['path']."\n";
```

Output:

```
http://www.thesite.com/download/eysjkss.zip
```

Comment: Just be careful. The value of $xml->file['path'] isn't a string. It's an instance of SimpleXMLElement.

Comment: Indeed. It can cause problems when comparing the value to another string but you can cast this value to a string beforehand  `(string)$xml->file['path']`

Comment: yeah but it's still an efficient way of doing it that I didn't know about, I still +1'ed your answer.

Answer (score 12):

To do it with [DOM](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) you do

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->load( 'file.xml' );
foreach( $dom->getElementsByTagName( 'file' ) as $file ) {
    echo $file->getAttribute( 'path' );
}
```

You can also do it with XPath:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->load( 'file.xml' );
$xPath = new DOMXPath( $dom );
foreach( $xPath->evaluate( '/files/file/@path' ) as $path ) {
    echo $path->nodeValue;
}
```

Or as a string value directly:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->load( 'file.xml' );
$xPath = new DOMXPath( $dom );
echo $xPath->evaluate( 'string(/files/file/@path)' );
```

You can fetch individual nodes also by traversing the DOM manually

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;
$dom->load( 'file.xml' );
echo $dom->documentElement->firstChild->getAttribute( 'path' );
```

*Marking this CW, because this has been answered before multiple times (just with different elements), including me, but I am too lazy to find the duplicate.*

Answer (score -1):

you can use PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser,this is a php library。http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Why introduce a 3rd party library when the built-in features are more than adequate for this task?

Comment: It is like jquery,Very convenient

Comment: Suggested third party alternatives to [SimpleHtmlDom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) that actually use [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) instead of String Parsing: [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/), [Zend_Dom](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.dom.html), [QueryPath](http://querypath.org/) and [FluentDom](http://www.fluentdom.org).