# XPath get attribute value in PHP

Tags: php, xpath

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
>   [How to extract a node attribute from XML using PHP's DOM Parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3993302/how-to-extract-a-node-attribute-from-xml-using-phps-dom-parser)

How do I extract an HTML tag value?

HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" name="text1" id="text1" value="need to get this">
```

PHP:

```
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com');
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
@$doc->loadHTML($homepage);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$filtered = $xpath->query("//input[@name='text1']");
```

How do I get `value` to be *"need to get this"*?

**Update:**

I got it working and hope it will help others too. After above code I got the value by:

```
echo $filtered->item(0)->getAttribute('value');
```

Comment: You will have to loop over your filtered elements `$filtered` via `foreach ($filtered as $element) { ... }`and check the node values / attributes yourself.

Comment: One option is the less-used `evaluate()` method, which will return the text or an empty string: `$xpath->evaluate('string(//input[@name="text1"]/@value)');`

Comment: This isn't really an _exact_ duplicate of the other question. This one is really a cross-environment xpath solution, the other is php specific.

Comment: To  use `evaluate`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/45010743/287948

Answer (score 40, accepted):

XPath can do the job of getting the value attribute with `$xpath->query("//input[@name='text1']/@value");`. Then you can iterate over the node list of attribute nodes and access the `$value` property of each attribute node.

Comment: just closevote please. its a duplicate

Answer (score 14):

Look at this DOM method:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php

```
$array_result = array();
foreach (filtered as $key => $value) {
    $array_result[] = $value->getAttribute('ID'); 
}
```

Answer (score 9):

I'm not familiar with the PHP syntax for this, but to select the value attribute you would use the following xpath:

```
//input[@name='text1']/@value
```

However xpath doesn't return strings, it returns nodes. You want the `nodeValue` of the node, so if PHP follows convention, that code would be:

```
 $xpath->query("//input[@name='text1']/@value")->item(0).nodeValue;
```

For learning purposes, keep in mind you always check the `nodeValue` property. So if you wanted the name of the same element, you'd use:

```
 $xpath->query("//input[@name]/@name")->item(0).nodeValue;
```

You'd probably like to make sure the query returns a non-null value before querying the `nodeValue` property as well.

Comment: Doesn't work. error `Undefined property: DOMNodeList::$value`

Comment: this works for me:$res = $xpath->query("//input[@name]/@name"); echo $res->item(0)->nodeValue;

Comment: The simplest way is using `evaluate`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/45010743/287948