# Extract Image src from XML file using XPath

Tags: php, xml, xpath, xml-parsing

I have an XMl file as follows:

```
<time>13:12</time>
    <date>02/15/13 </date>
    <image1 src="path/to/image.jpeg" height="180" width="144" style="border-color: #800000" border="1" />
```

I don't have a problem using xpath for all of the regular nodes such as "time" and "date" but I'm stuck on what expression to use to extract the "image1 src".

This doesn't work nor does it if I add src to it.

```
$items = $xml->xpath('/*image1');
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [php xpath get attribute value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8027323/php-xpath-get-attribute-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
$items = $xml->xpath('//image1/@src');
```

Comment: Any ideas on how to strip the url from the image, leaving just image.jpg to use with file_put_contents as it tries to save it as the full url path

Comment: @csuk1 > You need to parse the image path to search for the last `'/'` and then keep the rest

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this logic.

```
set serveroutput on
Declare
xl clob := '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Body>
<time>13:12</time>
<date>02/15/13 </date>
<image1 src="path/to/image.jpeg" height="180" width="144" style="border-color:#800000" border="1" />   
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>';

v_parser Xmlparser.Parser;
v_doc    XMLDOM.DOMDocument;
v_nodeList      XMLDOM.DOMNodeList;
v_attribute    varchar2(300);

Begin
v_parser := Xmlparser.newParser;
xmlparser.setValidationMode(v_parser, TRUE);
Xmlparser.parseClob(v_parser, xl);

v_doc := Xmlparser.getDocument(v_parser);
v_nodeList  := xslprocessor.selectNodes(XMLDOM.makeNode(v_doc), '//image1');
v_attribute := XMLDOM.getAttribute((XMLDOM.makeElement(XMLDOM.item(v_nodeList, 0))), 'src');

dbms_output.put_line(v_attribute);
End;
```

**Output:**
path/to/image.jpeg