# Simple dom document iteration

Tags: xpath, domdocument

I have an HTML as so:

```
 <html>
   <body>
      <div class="somethingunneccessary"></div>
      <div class="container">
         <div>
            <p>text1</p>
            <p>text2</p>
            <p>text3</p>
         </div>
         <div>
            <p>text4/p>
            <p>text5</p>
            <p>text6</p>
         </div>
         <div>
            <p>text7</p>
            <p>text8</p>
            <p>text9</p>
         </div>
         <div>
            <p>text10</p>
            <p>text11</p>
            <p>text12</p>
         </div>
         <div>
            <p>text13</p>
            <p>text14</p>
            <p>text15</p>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
 </html>
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is the following:

1./ Loop over the div elements within the div having a class `container`.

2./ During the iteration I want to grab the text from the 3rd `p tag`.

**The looping part is essential instead of just slicing out the p tags by themselves**

I've got some code done but it doesn't do looping:

```
$doc=new DOMDocument(); 
$doc->loadHTML($htmlsource);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$commentxpath = $xpath->query("/html/body/div[2]/div[5]/p[3]");
$commentdata = $commentxpath->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

How do I **loop through each inner div element and extract the 3rd p tag**.

Like I said, the looping is essential.

Comment: Have you tried using whatever mechanism your language uses for iterating over objects?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams That's what I need help with. Is adjusting the script to iterate over the container div inner div elements

Comment: So then what you're saying is that you have no idea how your language iterates?

Comment: do you wany take every 3rd p ?

Comment: @splash58 yes thats the goal to iterate over the div elements within the div having a class container and extract the 3rd p tag text

Comment: @splash58 Please look at my updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> During the iteration I want to grab the text from the 3rd p tag

Try:

```
"//div[@class='container']/div/p[3]"
```

This should return all third  p in all div inside of div with class container.

Comment: This works great. I have a further question. What If I wanted the values from the other p elements within each div. How can I change this query to get all the p tags from a div

Comment: Can you make a concrete example iterating over the div elements and storing each p element into a multidimensional array?

Comment: I do not now wat you are asking for. Is the question how to do a loop in php over the returnd noteset?

Comment: Yes please that is what I am looking for.

Comment: `foreach($commentxpath as $node) { 
        $p[] = $node->nodeValue; 
    }`?

Comment: Thanks this is great

Answer (score 0):

You may have to query over attributes: [php xpath get attribute value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8027323/php-xpath-get-attribute-value)

```
 $xpath->query("/html/body/div[@class='container']");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try

```
/html/body/div/div//p
```

That should return only the p elements XD