# PHP Simplehtmldom: Extra image url from data-src

Tags: php, html, regex, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I am trying to scrape a few images from a website by using the PHP Simplehtmldom library. Normally the image url is found in the 'src' but in this case the image url is found in the 'data-url'. I am having trouble to access the data-url value and I was hoping some could help me out.

Let's say I have the following code:

```
<section id="imagesContainer">
    <div class="img">
        <img data-src="https://example.com/image1.jpg" alt="imageAlt1">
    </div>
    <div class="img">
        <img data-src="https://example.com/image2.jpg" alt="imageAlt2">
    </div>
    <div class="img">
        <img data-src="https://example.com/image3.jpg" alt="imageAlt3">
    </div>
</section>
```

I attempted to extract the image urls from the data-src with the following code but it doesn't return the image url:

```
foreach($html->find('#imagesContainer') as $imagesContainer) {
    foreach($imagesContainer->find('img') as $image) {
        echo $image->data-src;

    }

}
```

How can I extract the image url from the data-src? Is it possible with the simplehtmldom or do I need a regex?

Comment: You definitely don't need regex. Just use XPath. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8027323/xpath-get-attribute-value-in-php

Answer (score 1):

many thanks for your suggestion. This code, using XPath, works to extract the value of the data-url:

```
 $image->getAttribute('data-src')
```