# Reading xml file in php

Tags: php, xml, file

I have a question regarding reading an xml file with php.
I have a sample php file:

///file.xml

```
 <appender name="app1">
      <param name="param1"></param>
 </appender>
```

Now i want to get the value of the param name. I have this code.

```
function getURL($aURL){

$objDOM = new DOMDocument();

////the file.xml    
$objDOM->load($aURL);  
$note = $objDOM->getElementsByTagName("appender");

foreach ( $note as $value)  {
    ///First try
    $name = $value->getElementsByTagName("name")->firstChild->nodeValue;

    ///Second try
    ///$logName = $value->getElementsByTagName("name");
    ///$name = $logName->item(0)->nodeValue;

}
```

}

For my First and Second try both returns empty. Does not give the
"app1" value.

Can someone help me on this?

Thank you.

Comment: *(related)* [Noob Question about DOMDocument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979836/noob-question-about-domdocument-in-php/4983721#4983721)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to extract a node attribute from XML using PHP's DOM Parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3993302/how-to-extract-a-node-attribute-from-xml-using-phps-dom-parser)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the tag is **param** and the name of the attribute is **name**:

```
$name = $value->getElementsByTagName("param")->firstChild->getAttribute('name')->nodeValue;
```

Comment: thanks @Secator but  but it seems to not work :( gives me this "Object of class DOMElement could not be converted to string in" error

Comment: Try adding `->nodeValue` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

name is not an element, it's an **attribute** of the appender element

```
$name = $value->getElementsByTagName("param")->firstChild->getAttribute("name");
```

**EDIT**

```
$data = '<appender name="app1">
    <param name="param1"></param>
    <param name="param2"></param>
</appender>';

$objDOM = new DOMDocument();
$objDOM->loadXML($data);

$appenders = $objDOM->getElementsByTagName("appender");

foreach ($appenders as $appender)  {
    $params = $appender->getElementsByTagName("param");
    foreach($params as $param) {
        $name = $param->getAttribute("name");
        var_dump($name);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks @Mark Baker. but it seems to not work :( gives me this "Object of class DOMElement could not be converted to string in" error

Answer (score 1):

@Tinks with "SimpleXML" its a bit easier to read the values.

```
<?php
  $xmlString = '<appender name="app1">
      <param name="param1" value="2">123</param>
      <param name="param2" value="3">345</param>
 </appender>';

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlString);

foreach($xml->param as $out) {
    echo $out['name']."  ";
    echo $out['value']."<br />";
}
?>
```

Here is a short example how to read an xml file.

Comment: but because i need to load the file first since it is a different xml file @Stony

Comment: then use file_get_contents('file.xml') to get the content.

new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents('file.xml'));

Answer (score 0):

Your `nodeValue` is really empty. According to `<param name="param1"></param>` , you did not specify one. Use `getAttribute` method instead.

Answer (score -1):

Here's what to do:

```
Load the XML file
Get the name of the first element
Create a loop that will trigger on each child node, using the children() function
Output the element name and data for each child node
```