# Select Class Name value in DOMXPath

Tags: php, html, dom, domdocument, domxpath

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to extract a node attribute from XML using PHP’s DOM Parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3993302/how-to-extract-a-node-attribute-from-xml-using-phps-dom-parser)

I have HTML like this:

```
   <tr class="calendar_row" data-eventid="48256">
   ...
   </tr>
```

I just want to select the value or `data-eventid` across the web page but I don't have any idea how to do it in xpath. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `@` to get at attributes.

```
//assume $dom is a DOMDocument

$finder = new DOMXPath($dom);
//  //tr[@data-eventid] = all tr nodes that have a data-eventid attribute
//    /@data-eventid = the attribute node itself as opposed to the tr node
$nodes = $finder->query('//tr[@data-eventid]/@data-eventid');

foreach($nodes as $node) {
    echo $node->nodeValue."\n"; // echos your data-eventid value ie. 48256
}
```

Comment: this code is working..thank you so much for your help!